# How to get the list of all events from Fabric

Tags: google-fabric

I am using Answers of Fabric to track the custom event in my app.
I understand that the webpage gives me only top 10 category.
My question is whether there is any workaround to get the list of all events.
If another services do provide the whole list, please kindly recommend one.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Currently it's not possible to get more then the top 10 event attributes.

Comment: Good Job, Fabric Team !!!!

Comment: I heard that I can access the raw data if I use Fabric.  Probably I can get the list of the whole events.